# Mysterious java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java

I get following exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3693019260"
```

while calling

```
Integer.parseInt(s);
```

And I don't know why I get it.

- 3693019260 is smaller than 2^32
- 3693019260 is clearly a natural number
- the String is cleared from all non-digit elements with `s.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")`

So why do I get this exception?

According to the little bit of debugging I did, I saw that the number dips under `multmin` but I don't know what this variable does and how I should interpret this observation.

Comment: You need to describe how you're parsing the string, preferably with your code.

Comment: @pvg done, totally forgot that xD

Comment: Yes, including original code is usually necessary, but I managed to deduce he's using `Integer.parseInt` or one of its friends.

Comment: Answer has you covered. Just use a long not an int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `3693019260` may fit into a 32 bit unsigned integer, it looks like you are trying to parse it into a plain `int` which is a signed integer. Signed simply means that it supports negative values using `-`.

With signed numbers, half of the namespace is reserved, so your number must fit into 2^32÷2−1 `2147483647` instead of simply 2^32.

The simplest fix is to parse the value as a `long` instead of an `int`. Long numbers are 64 bits and support many more digits in the string.

Comment: Might want to add that signed int goes up to `2147483647` aka `2^31-1`

Comment: ok, that was pretty stupid of me, thanks xD

Comment: @Kiskae He wrote *2^32/2-1* which is the same thing.